# How can I create a button with image in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created a button in SwiftUI with these line of codes:

```
Button(action: {
    print("button pressed")
}) {
    Image("marker")
}
```

but `marker` image automatically changes to blue color.

I want to use original image in button.

this is original `marker.png`:

[image]

but SwiftUI changes it to this:

[image]

I remember we have tintColor or something like this in `UIButton`, but I can't find it in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Go to the image and change the Render As "Original Image"
[image]

Answer (score 59):

Another way to set programmatically:-

```
var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
          print("button pressed")

        }) {
            Image("marker")
            .renderingMode(Image.TemplateRenderingMode?.init(Image.TemplateRenderingMode.original))
        }
    }
```

Comment: `.renderingMode(.original)` works for me and is much cleaner!

Comment: When I try this, it includes a white bar behind the image.  Is there a way to hide the white bar, but show the image?

Answer (score 32):

You can try this:

```
var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
          print("button pressed")

        }) {
            Image("marker")
            .renderingMode(.original)
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 8):

> SwiftUI

```
var body: some View {
      HStack {
           Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "Login")!)
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)

           Text("Login")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this

- 1st through the **attribute inspector** -

[image]

- 2nd through **.renderingMode()** modifier -

> ```
> Image("ImageName")    
>    .resizable()    
>    .renderingMode(.original)   
>    .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
> ```